# How to categorise/tag WSS wiki pages?

Tags: wiki, wss-3.0, categories, 2007, tagging

I am using the WSS wiki, and as it's getting bigger I could really do with organising the pages better.

Is there a good way to categorise wiki pages into groups/categories, or even to tag them?

I am able to add the 'Category' or 'Categories' columns to the wiki list (not sure what the difference is between the two...), but there's no real lookup there, they're just single lines of text.  It would be nice if there was then a way to filter and search based on multiple categories, or just to click on a category link and see all pages within that category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I create my own "Category" column and set the type to "choice". Specify my choices, and all set! You can then leverage that to build a "Table of Contents" grouped by Category (as long as pages can only be part of 1 category).

There's a great HowTo here: [Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jackiebo/supercharge-your-sharepoint-wiki-adding-columns-and-creating-dynamic-tables)

One step further (if you want to allow others to be able to add more categories without giving them additional access) create a custom list (e.g. "Wiki_Categories"). Then create a new "item" for each category. Go back to your wiki library and add a new "lookup" column. Label it "Category" and point it to the appropriate field in your new Wiki_Categories list.

To create a quick "tag could":
Follow similar steps. Create a new column (called "Tags"?), and set it to a choice field and allow multiple selections. Or, using the "one step further" from above, create a "Wiki_Tags" list, and create a new "Tags" lookup column in your wiki library - allowing multiple selections.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure though but maybe create a choice dropdown column and use that.
So when creating your pages select the coresponding category.
hope that helps

Comment: That's a good answer, Patrick.

Answer (score -1):

This is great information and currently playing around with building wiki pages and lists in SP Server 2007.

I've followed the recommendations stated above and now have a Tag list but since it's not actually visible to the user at the time of wiki writing, it doesn't function like a tag cloud should (i.e. provide visual cues for tags).

Does SP Server 2007 allow wikis to be tagged? Does SP Server 2007 allow making a real tag cloud? (I see it's a web part in 2010).

What would really help me then is:

The ability to search for all wikis by associated tags. I don't see how I can make the Advanced Search web part allow me to search for content in my custom ("Tag") columns.

Is there anyway to search by "tags" i.e. Items in a List?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. See [How do I ask questions here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask) for further help.